# Ajax call same id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Im using an ajax call to accomplish the this: When you click on the link it displays it creates a link at the bottom with the same text.

**HTML :**

```
 <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="addtable" href="#">Add+</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="table">Table1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="table">Table2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="table">Table4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="trial"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addtable').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {loadpage: 'addtable'},
            url: 'addtable.php',
            success: function(data){    
            $('#trial').html(data);
            } 
        }); //ajax request
    }); //change function
}); //document ready

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {loadpage: $(this).text()},
            url: 'addtable.php',
            success: function(data){    
            $('#trial').html(data);
            } 
        }); //ajax request
    }); //change f
});
```

**PHP (addtable.php) :**

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['loadpage'];
?>
```

When I click on addtable it displays it at the bottom of the list(thats what I wanted) it does that too when I click on table one(it displays table one) but however when I click on table two or table three it doesnt do anything. I think its something to do with them having the same id which is table, I think jquery uses the first one it sees, Does anyone know how to solve that so that it displays table two and three when I click on them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ids should be unique on a page, if you want to have all of the tables share the same click action, use a class or a data- attribute: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: IDs not only *should* be unique, they **have** to be. Browsers will take it because they're nice like that but any time you redeclare an ID, it overwrites the reference to that ID. It's like if you apply one CSS style then overwrite it later in the file. The last one will win out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` should be unique in same document replace duplicate ids by general `class`, like :

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="addtable" href="#">Add+</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="table">Table1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="table">Table2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="table">Table4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="trial"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then use dot `.` (class selector) in your js :

```
$('.table').click(function(){
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="addtable" href="#">Add+</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="table">Table1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="table">Table2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="table">Table4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="trial"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$("[data-id='table']").click(function(){...})
```

Data-id or class